# Entity Framework - How to create a base entity without generics

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics

Is there a way to write a base *entity*, where the primary key's type is not specified using generics?

For instance, I have been doing this so far:

```
public class BaseUniqueEntity<T> where T : IComparable, IComparable<T> {
    [Key]
    public T Key{ get; set; }
}
```

This was good at the time, but now is giving me design problems. For example, when coding a generic repository I am obligued to specify two type constraints:

```
public interface IRepository<K, E>
    where K : IComparable, IComparable<K>
    where E : BaseUniqueEntity<K>
```

I would only want to specify the entity's type `E`, but I need the `K` type for specifying the `where E : BaseUniqueEntity<K>` constraint.

I can't make `Key` of type object, because it messes up when creating my tables for me.

So I was think of removing generics from `BaseUniqueEntity`. Is there a way to accomplish this? I'm out of ideas and I'm pretty new to Entity Framework.

Comment: You can - make it something that's fully defined: `int`, `Guid`, `string`, whatever. But then all your entities will have to have primary key typed as that.

Comment: I would really love that child classes could decide what type their key would be

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to write a base entity, where the primary key's type is not specified using generics?

Why must you write a base entity? Ostensibly, all you're doing is trying to enforce a key on each entity, and that might not even make sense for the type (composite keys might make more sense, which EF supports). Regardless, the Key attribute is required for an entity anyway, so what is being enforced exactly?

There's no rule saying that everything must inherit from a base class. My advice: if you don't think it makes sense for callers to always define the key type, then just write classes that define their own keys, with types that make sense for the them.

Comment: But If there's no abstract or base class, and therefore no base `Key` property, how can I build a generic repository? How would I get the entity's key if its known only by the implementation entity?

Comment: @MatiCicero Reflection. Something like this should work: var keyProperty = entity.GetProperties().Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(KeyAttribute)));

Comment: @MatiCicero Why do you need to know the `Key` property to build a repo? Have you seen the `DbSet.Find` method? Have you exposed the `IQueryable<T>`? This is not a case of Inheritance. Does it satisfy Listkov?

Answer (score 0):

How about keep the generic IRepository interface and define another interface as a shortcut for default key (int, guid, etc)
Something like this:

```
public interface IRepository<K, E>
    where K : IComparable, IComparable<K>
    where E : BaseUniqueEntity<K>
{
}

public interface IRepository<E> : IRepository<int, E>
    where E : BaseUniqueEntity<int>
{
}
```

When defining concrete Repository:

```
public class UserRepository<User>
{
}
```

Comment: This approach came to my mind too, but I don't like the idea of creating new `IRepisotry` for each possible type of `Key`